# React-native - AndroidManifest.xml Error: "attribute android:namespace not found"

Tags: android, react-native, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, android-manifest

I'm encountering an issue with my React Native project's AndroidManifest.xml during the build process. The error message I'm receiving is as follows:

Execution failed for task ':app:bundleReleaseResources'.
Android resource linking failed
I:*******\android\app\build\intermediates\bundle_manifest\release\AndroidManifest.xml:99: error: attribute android:namespace not found.
error: failed processing manifest.
The strange thing is that the android:namespace attribute seems to be added automatically during the compilation, and I haven't manually added it to the AndroidManifest.xml file. Even if i add it myself, i got the error.

I've already checked my project's dependencies, Gradle configurations, and custom tasks to make sure nothing is causing this issue, but I'm still stuck.

If anyone has encountered a similar problem or has suggestions on how to debug and resolve this issue, I'd greatly appreciate your help. Here are the specific details:

I'm using React Native for my project.
I'm using Gradle for the build system.

What I already tried :

- Adding namespace in app/build.gradle
- Gradle sync
- ./gradlew clean
- caches clean
- Editting the AndroidManifest.xml files manually

Any insights or solutions to resolve this issue would be highly valuable. Thank you in advance for your assistance!